# Samsung build number and rooting SM-G900P

Tags: rooting, root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-5, sprint

I would like to root my Boost Mobile  Samsung S5. I've read up enough to know that I need to be 100% about the model and software build version before proceeding with the root.

My provider: Boost/Sprint 
Model: SM-G900P 
Build: `mmb29m.g900pvpu3cpg1`
Android 6.0.1

I've looked around and found confirmations for this build with one difference, the builds confirmed don't have the "`1`" at the end of the build I.D.

Can anyone explain the significance of the 1 at the end of my build?

Also will I need to reactivate my service if I root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reference](http://www.igitblog.com/samsung-build-number/)

> Can anyone explain the significance of the 1 at the end

Quoting from reference

> ....The last character is actually the version number or revising code in that specific month

It is not of significance when choosing firmware, it is only a minor build variation

> Also will I need to reactivate my service if I root?

No

Comment: Thank you! So ill go ahead and proceed with the root.  Do you know of a good program to use for this model?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Thanks. Best place for detailed instructions and getting user experiences is XDA. [This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2742994) would be a good starting point to read

Comment: We have a rooting guide on this site also. http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/131553